# Page rank MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

trying to fix my code that does page rank. Not sure why the power method and the backslash are coming up with different answers and which is wrong and how to fix it.

```
    p=rand(length(M),1);
    pnorm=norm(p,1);
    p=p/pnorm;
    n=length(M);

    d=0;
    e=ones(n,1);
    a=1/n;
    Z=a*(e*e');
    Mtilda=d*M+(1-d)*Z;


    for k=1:n
        tic;
        prev_p = p;
        z = Mtilda*p;
        p = z/norm(z,2);
        dl_p = norm(p-prev_p, 2);
        t(k)=toc;
        str=sprintf('for d=%g , iteration %d: time=%11.4g',d,k,t(k));
        disp(str);
    if dl_p < 1e-6; break; end
    end


    ReportPageRank(p,U,0.005)
    d=1;
    p2 =(eye(n)-d*M)\((((1-d)/n)*e));
```

Comment: it seems to be out by a factor of 2 so i cant be completely wrong.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the array `M` represents? Also, what is the definition of `ReportPageRank(p,U,0,005)` function? What are the parameters `p`, `U`, and `0.005`? This way I may run it on my machine. What was the intention of the last two lines of code? They don't seem to have any purpose.

Comment: I had to compare the backslash operator. I now have it working luckily. I had to set up the power method differently and it for some reason worked.

Comment: Can you add an edit to your question where you explain what was the issue with the pseudo-inverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've figured it out, but I'll post my work anyways in case someone's interested in the implementation.

```
M = ...
[  0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.50000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   1.00000   0.50000   0.33333   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.33333   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   0.50000   1.00000   1.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.33333   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
   0.09091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000];
N = length(M);
PR = (1/N)*ones(length(M),1);   %define PageRank vector for t = 0
d = 0.85;                       %define damping rate
iter = 1;
delta_PR = Inf;                 %set initial error to infinity
while delta_PR > 1e-6           %iterate until error is less than 1e-6
    tic;

    prev_PR = PR;               %save previous PageRank vector (t-1)
    PR = d*M*PR + ((1-d)/N)*ones(N,1);  %calculate new PageRank (t)

    delta_PR = norm(PR-prev_PR);%calculate new error
    t(iter)=toc;
    str=sprintf('for d=%g , iteration %d: time=%11.4g',delta_PR,iter,t(iter));
    disp(str);
    iter = iter + 1;
end

powerRank = pinv((eye(length(M)) - d*M))*(((1-d)/N)*ones(length(M),1));

PR = powerRank =

    0.0328
    0.3844
    0.3429
    0.0391
    0.0809
    0.0391
    0.0162
    0.0162
    0.0162
    0.0162
    0.0162
```